# how to avoid handling a deep link twice on cordova android application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, branch.io

I am facing an issue with regards to branch io deep linking.

Environment: I am using
Android Marshmallow SDK, platform: 25
Cordova 7.0.1 and
Branch SDK
"io.branch.sdk": "~2.2.3"
"branch-cordova-sdk": "^2.2.5",

Below are the scenarions in which im facing issue:

Scenario 1: Calling Branch.InitSession in OnResume call back function.
Failed case:
Steps:

Installed the app for the first time. (Did not open the app)
clicked on Branch IO Deep Link,
It opens up the app on my phone, but does not redirect to the url that is specified in the parameters of the Deep Link, as the InitSession is being called twice.
a) In the OnDeviceReady call back function.
b) In the OnResume Function ( This is because, since my app is opening for the first time, it request the user for permission, which pauses the application and resumes when user deny's/ approves the permission calling the onresume method).
Second time when the InitSession is invoked from OnResume call back it recives empty parameters from Deep Link and the application does not redirect to the URL as expected.
Scenario 2: If i remove the Branch.InitSession in OnResume call back fucntion.
Success case: The above scenario works well, if remove the InitSession in OnResume function
Failed case:

Installed the app.
Opened the app and let the app be in the background.
Clicked on a Branch IO deep link.
The application does not recieve the deep link data or the parameters to process the information, since the initsession is not avaible in the onresume method.
Can you please let me know how to handle such a scenario, let me know if i need to publish any further information which might help you in finding if i am implementing it in wrong way.

Thanks & Regards,
Jyothi.

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io). As commented by our Cordova expert on the Github issue [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/issues/358)

It looks like you have 2 versions of Branch installed:

"io.branch.sdk": "~2.2.3"
"branch-cordova-sdk": "^2.2.5",

`io.branch.sdk` is our outdated Branch SDK which is no longer supported. We would recommend following this [guide](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#compiling-updating-the-branch-sdk) to make sure you are only running one version of the Branch SDK. You can also follow the [integration guide](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking#getting-started) on our Github repo for the Cordova SDK.